# Using Python Parser of Label Expression to only show text after particular symbol?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

I have a bunch of point data that needs labeling. However the attribute used for labeling is more complex than is needed in the map.

Example of the attribute field for labeling:

- 15/8-9a,
- 001/15-2
- 8/19-13

What we need to see labeled is any number and/or letter found after the "-" symbol. 
So from the above example: **9a, 2, 13** will be displayed on the map.

I know this can be done with slicing but since the number of characters after "-" is variable I'm struggling a little with the expression.

I do not want to add a new field so am exploring writing a label expression.

Does anyone know what the expression might look like to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Python expression like the following by checking Advanced on the Label Expression dialog of the Labels tab of the Properties dialog:

```
def FindLabel ( [TestField] ):
  return [TestField].split("-")[1]
```

This relies on there only being one occurrence of "-" in the field.

Answer (score 3):

First, the resource page to help you in the future:  [Building label expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000027000000)

There are a lot of examples on that page, including Python, VBScript and JScript.

If it were me, building the expression in VBScript, I would use a combination of the Instr, Len, and Mid functions.  If it is supported, use the InStrRev function, as that would let you search for the first instance of a "-" starting from the right.

You want to find the position of the "-" in the string, then count from there to the end of the string.

The definition of the `Mid` function is (Input String, Start Position, Number of Characters)

```
Mid([string],Instrrev([string],'-')+1,len([string])-instrrev([string],'-')
```

You just build your label function around this.  Adding 1 to the Instrrev moves you to the character beyond the "-".

The bottom of that help document has links to string references for Python and VBScript.  They are both exceedingly helpful for remembering these sorts of operations.  I would look at Python as it can probably accomplish this same activity with a much smaller function length.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def FindLabel ( [name_field] ):
 a=[name_field]
 l=a.rfind("-")+1
 a=a[l:]
 return a
```